# Ошибка "Dependency requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later"

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle, androidx

Хочу обновить библиотеку `androidx.core:core` с `1.7.0` до `1.9.0`, но получаю следующую ошибку:

> 3 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:
>
> 1. Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs.
>
>    :app is currently compiled against android-32.
>
>    Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.
>
>    Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed on).
> 2. ...

Файл `build.gradle` выглядит так:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.myapplication'
    compileSdk 32
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }   
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.3'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.support:support-compat:26.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Добавьте полный текст ошибки [в вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1476155/edit).

Comment: добавил, в статью тему

Comment: В сообщение об ошибке же написано, какие зависимости конфликтуют. Уберите ненужную.

Comment: Пожалуйста, прикладывайте текстовую информацию в виде текста, а не скриншотами, чтобы можно было копировать и искать, не перепечатывая. Кроме этого, в вашем вопросе сразу несколько проблем, сформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы он был сфокуирован только на одной проблеме (ошибке).

Comment: нужно исправить последнюю, остальные помог решить Vadik, эти ошибки вышли при попытке решить последнюю проблему  и она серавно не решилась, она есть в текстовом варианте, я не понимаю какую библиотеку надо убрать для исчезновения проблемы

Comment: Потрудитесь текстовую информацию выложить текстом, а не скриншотами. Тогда ваш вопрос может быть будет полезен кому-то еще в будущем. В таком виде ваш вопрос не несет пользы для сообщества. Вторая ошибка -- это уже другая проблема. Одна проблема -- один вопрос. Пожалуйста, заведите [новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) по другой проблеме. И если по первой проблеме ответ помог, то засчитайте ответ.

Comment: Удалил нерелевантные скриншоты, так как вторая ошибка [перенесена](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1477247) в другой вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Библиотека `androidx.core:core` версии `1.9.0` [требует](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core#1.9.0-alpha05), чтобы версия `compileSdk` в вашем проекте была выставлена в значение `33` или выше.

Чтобы исправить ошибку, вы можете понизить версию этой библиотеки до `1.8.0` (не рекомендуется), либо обновить `compileSdk` и `targetSdk` до версии `33`:

```
android {
    compileSdk 33
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdk 33
        ...

    }
}
```

Comment: при изменении ошибки исправляются, кроме последней

Comment: как исправить последнюю

Comment: @daichi, заведите отдельный вопрос для другой ошибки

Answer (score -1):

Просто выключите переключатель «Автономный режим» .

В верхней правой части окна.

Нажмите на опцию Gradle 2nd number (рядом с опцией «Настройка»), нажмите на нее, после чего вы сможете работать непрерывно.

Как вы можете видеть изображение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это не помогает