# Ошибка "Duplicate class found" при подключении Room

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-room, androidx

Значит хотел, подключить библиотеку room, а тут это:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
       > Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
         Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
         Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
         Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
         Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
         Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
         Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
         Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
         Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
         Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.9.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) and support-compat-26.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
         
         Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

Файл builad.gradle выглядит так:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.myapplication'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {


    implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.3'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.support:support-compat:26.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Вы подключили допотопную версию - смотрите актуальную здесь https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#declaring_dependencies

Comment: У вас уже подключен Room в первых двух строчках (`androidx.room`). Уберите последние две строчки (`android.arch.persistence.room`). Также рекомендую убрать зависимости `androidx.support`. Приложите в вопрос содержимое файла `gradle.properties`, интересует опция `android.useAndroidX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы подключить [Room](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#declaring_dependencies), используйте эти зависимости:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.3"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.3"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3"
```

Эти зависимости не стоит использовать, они [устарели](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/package-summary):

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
```

> Пакеты `android.arch` Архитектурных Компонентов больше не поддерживаются. Они были заменены на соответствующие пакеты [`androidx.*`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate). Смотрите [`androidx.room`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/package-summary).

Comment: спасибо, большое

Answer (score 0):

Для Java мне помогло в build.gradle:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.0"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.0"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0"
```

И в gradle.properties файле добавить:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```